# scala play reactivemongo java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get

Tags: scala

I get exception thrown when i try to update mongodb document using reactive mongo plugin. Any help is appreciated . Thank you

```
DiagramDAO.updateDiagram(diagramId,initial.get).onComplete { 
    case Failure(e) =>  Logger.debug("Diagram failed to go to initial state    "+e.printStackTrace())  
    case Success(writeResult) => println(s"successfully updated document with     initial state: $writeResult")
    }
```

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get    at
>   scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)     at
>   scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)     at
>   play.api.libs.json.JsLookupResult$class.get(JsLookup.scala:98)    at
>   play.api.libs.json.JsUndefined.get(JsLookup.scala:127)    at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$$anonfun$reads$7$$anonfun$apply$30$$anonfun$apply$31$$anonfun$apply$32$$anonfun$apply$33$$anonfun$apply$34$$anonfun$apply$35$$anonfun$apply$39.apply(jsoncollection.scala:281)
>     at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$$anonfun$reads$7$$anonfun$apply$30$$anonfun$apply$31$$anonfun$apply$32$$anonfun$apply$33$$anonfun$apply$34$$anonfun$apply$35$$anonfun$apply$39.apply(jsoncollection.scala:277)
>     at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.flatMap(JsResult.scala:107)    at
>   play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess.flatMap(JsResult.scala:9)    at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$$anonfun$reads$7$$anonfun$apply$30$$anonfun$apply$31$$anonfun$apply$32$$anonfun$apply$33$$anonfun$apply$34$$anonfun$apply$35.apply(jsoncollection.scala:277)
>     at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$$anonfun$reads$7$$anonfun$apply$30$$anonfun$apply$31$$anonfun$apply$32$$anonfun$apply$33$$anonfun$apply$34$$anonfun$apply$35.apply(jsoncollection.scala:276)
>     at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.flatMap(JsResult.scala:107)    at
>   play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess.flatMap(JsResult.scala:9)    at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$$anonfun$reads$7$$anonfun$apply$30$$anonfun$apply$31$$anonfun$apply$32$$anonfun$apply$33$$anonfun$apply$34.apply(jsoncollection.scala:276)
>     at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$$anonfun$reads$7$$anonfun$apply$30$$anonfun$apply$31$$anonfun$apply$32$$anonfun$apply$33$$anonfun$apply$34.apply(jsoncollection.scala:275)
>     at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.flatMap(JsResult.scala:107)    at
>   play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess.flatMap(JsResult.scala:9)    at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$$anonfun$reads$7$$anonfun$apply$30$$anonfun$apply$31$$anonfun$apply$32$$anonfun$apply$33.apply(jsoncollection.scala:275)
>     at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$$anonfun$reads$7$$anonfun$apply$30$$anonfun$apply$31$$anonfun$apply$32$$anonfun$apply$33.apply(jsoncollection.scala:274)
>     at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.flatMap(JsResult.scala:107)    at
>   play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess.flatMap(JsResult.scala:9)    at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$$anonfun$reads$7$$anonfun$apply$30$$anonfun$apply$31$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(jsoncollection.scala:274)
>     at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$$anonfun$reads$7$$anonfun$apply$30$$anonfun$apply$31$$anonfun$apply$32.apply(jsoncollection.scala:273)
>     at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.flatMap(JsResult.scala:107)    at
>   play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess.flatMap(JsResult.scala:9)    at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$$anonfun$reads$7$$anonfun$apply$30$$anonfun$apply$31.apply(jsoncollection.scala:273)
>     at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$$anonfun$reads$7$$anonfun$apply$30$$anonfun$apply$31.apply(jsoncollection.scala:272)
>     at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.flatMap(JsResult.scala:107)    at
>   play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess.flatMap(JsResult.scala:9)    at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$$anonfun$reads$7$$anonfun$apply$30.apply(jsoncollection.scala:272)
>     at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$$anonfun$reads$7$$anonfun$apply$30.apply(jsoncollection.scala:271)
>     at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.flatMap(JsResult.scala:107)    at
>   play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess.flatMap(JsResult.scala:9)    at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$$anonfun$reads$7.apply(jsoncollection.scala:271)
>     at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$$anonfun$reads$7.apply(jsoncollection.scala:270)
>     at play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.flatMap(JsResult.scala:107)    at
>   play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess.flatMap(JsResult.scala:9)    at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONBatchCommands$LastErrorReader$.reads(jsoncollection.scala:270)
>     at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.JSONSerializationPack$.deserialize(json.scala:376)
>     at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.JSONSerializationPack$.deserialize(json.scala:350)
>     at
>   reactivemongo.api.SerializationPack$class.readAndDeserialize(serializationpack.scala:24)
>     at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.JSONSerializationPack$.readAndDeserialize(json.scala:350)
>     at
>   reactivemongo.api.SerializationPack$class.readAndDeserialize(serializationpack.scala:32)
>     at
>   play.modules.reactivemongo.json.JSONSerializationPack$.readAndDeserialize(json.scala:350)
>     at
>   reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericCollection$$anonfun$update$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(genericcollection.scala:297)
>     at
>   reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericCollection$$anonfun$update$1$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(genericcollection.scala:297)
>     at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:236)   at
>   scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)  at
>   scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:236)     at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)    at
>   scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235)    at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)  at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>   [debug] - application - Diagram failed to go to initial state ()

Comment: Its very very very strange error!!! What is the version of Mongo, play and reactivemongo driver? Do you use default WriteConcern or have custom implementation? IMHO try to use `BSONSerializationPack` from original driver instead of `JSONSerializationPack` from play mongo driver. Finally, turn on jvm debug and find what json  is parsed in `play.api.libs.json.JsLookup.scala:98` class.

Answer (score 2):

As your stack says you're trying to get value of None. Try to avoid using method 'get' on Option. For your case you can use 'map':

```
initial.map(valueOfInitial =>
  DiagramDAO.updateDiagram(diagramId, valueOfInitial).onComplete { 
    ...
  }
)
```

Comment: I made the changes with no luck. DiagramDAO.updateDiagram Future is resulting Failure on completion, however when I query mongodb document has been updated successfully.

Answer (score 1):

`Option.get` is the devil, avoid it.. here is another way

```
initial foreach { ival =>
    DiagramDAO.updateDiagram(diagramId,ival).onComplete { 
        case Failure(e) =>  Logger.debug("Diagram failed to go to initial state    "+e.printStackTrace())  
        case Success(writeResult) => println(s"successfully updated document with     initial state: $writeResult")
    }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned above, I have tried this but exception still persists.